# Adding fields to existing detailsview form

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have an existing detailsview form that works fine. I added 7 new fields to it, databound textboxes. When page loads however, there are no errors but detailsview is disabled. Can't find a solution to why this is.

```
        <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView2" runat="server" `AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="intaccno,intsequenceno"`
    DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource3" Height="4px" Width="349px" 
    DefaultMode="Edit" onitemupdated="DetailsView2_ItemUpdated" 
    CellPadding="4" EnableModelValidation="True" ForeColor="#333333" 
    GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    <CommandRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        There is not data to display
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
    <FieldHeaderStyle BackColor="#E9ECF1" Font-Bold="True" />
    <Fields>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="txt1status">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtStatus" runat="server" Enabled="False" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("txt1status") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkCancelReview" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                    oncheckedchanged="chkCancelReview_CheckedChanged" 
                    Text="Cancel Review (only approvers can cancel)" Visible="False" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Enabled="False" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("txt1status") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("txt1status") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="BMS Comments">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Height="61px" ReadOnly="True" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("systemcomments") %>' TextMode="MultiLine" Width="786px"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("systemcomments") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("systemcomments") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CRR" SortExpression="CreditRiskRating">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CreditRiskRating") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CreditRiskRating") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CreditRiskRating") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CQR" SortExpression="CreditQualityRating">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CreditQualityRating") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox14" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CreditQualityRating") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CreditQualityRating") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SCLT" SortExpression="SugarcaneLoanTemplate">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox11" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SugarcaneLoanTemplate") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox15" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SugarcaneLoanTemplate") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label15" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SugarcaneLoanTemplate") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Valuation" SortExpression="Valuation">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox12" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Valuation") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox16" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Valuation") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label16" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Valuation") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Financials" SortExpression="Financials">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox13" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Financials") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox17" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Financials") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label17" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Financials") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="BSCP" SortExpression="BusinessSuccessionContinuityPlan">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox14" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BusinessSuccessionContinuityPlan") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox18" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BusinessSuccessionContinuityPlan") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label18" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BusinessSuccessionContinuityPlan") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="IOA" SortExpression="InsuranceofAssets">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox15" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("InsuranceofAssets") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox19" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("InsuranceofAssets") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label19" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("InsuranceofAssets") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SecurityComments" SortExpression="SecurityComments">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SecurityComments") %>' Height="67px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="750px"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SecurityComments") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SecurityComments") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ServiceabilityComments" SortExpression="ServiceabilityComments">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox8" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("ServiceabilityComments") %>' Height="47px" TextMode="MultiLine" 
                    Width="750px" CausesValidation="True"></asp:TextBox>

            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ServiceabilityComments") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ServiceabilityComments") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comments" SortExpression="Comments">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox9" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Comments") %>' Height="179px" Width="756px" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox9" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Comments") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Comments") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Recommendation" SortExpression="Recommendation">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox10" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Recommendation") %>' Height="196px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="746px"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox10" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Recommendation") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Recommendation") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Approver's Comments" 
            SortExpression="txt90report">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("txt90report") %>' 
                    TextMode="MultiLine" Width="797px"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("txt90report") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("txt90report") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SBMComments">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSBMComments" runat="server" Height="75px" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("SBMComments") %>' TextMode="MultiLine" Width="589px"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SBMOfficer">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSBMOfficer" runat="server" Enabled="False" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("SBMOfficer") %>' Width="207px"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Send For Approval" 
            SortExpression="SentForApproval">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                &nbsp;<asp:CheckBox ID="chkSend" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("SentForApproval") %>'
                    Style="position: relative" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox11" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind`("SentForApproval") %>'></asp:TextBox>`
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind

("SentForApproval") %>'></asp:Label>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Review Officer" `SortExpression="reviewOfficer">`
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind`("reviewOfficer") %>'` 
                    Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox12" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind`("reviewOfficer") %>'></asp:TextBox>`
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind

("reviewOfficer") %>'></asp:Label>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Approver" SortExpression="Approver">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 

SelectedValue='<%# Bind("BranchManager") %>'

                    Style="position: relative" 

DataSourceID="ObjectDataSourceUsers" 

                    DataTextField="txt60name" DataValueField="txt60name" `Width="134px"` 
                    AppendDataBoundItems="True">
                    <asp:ListItem>Rudra Singh</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>RUDRA SINGH</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox13" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind

("BranchManager") %>'></asp:TextBox>

            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind

("BranchManager") %>'></asp:Label>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Approve">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkApprove" runat="server" Checked='<%# `Bind("Approved") %>'` 
                    Text="Click here to approve" Visible="False" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
    </Fields>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" 

HorizontalAlign="Center" />

             <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
    </asp:DetailsView>

        using System;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Security;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
    using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Web.SessionState;
    using System.Text;
    public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
            CheckBox chkApprove = (CheckBox)DetailsView2.FindControl("chkApprove");
            CheckBox chkSendForApproval = (CheckBox)DetailsView2.FindControl("chkSend");
            TextBox reviewOfficer = (TextBox)DetailsView2.FindControl("textbox3");
            TextBox Status = (TextBox)DetailsView2.FindControl("textbox4");
            TextBox ManagerComments = (TextBox)DetailsView2.FindControl("textbox2");
            TextBox SBMOfficer = (TextBox)DetailsView2.FindControl("txtSBMOfficer");
            TextBox SBMComments = (TextBox)DetailsView2.FindControl("txtSBMComments");
            CheckBox chkCancelReview = (CheckBox)DetailsView2.FindControl("chkCancelReview");

            chkCancelReview.Visible = false;



            if (User.IsInRole("ReviewApprover"))
            {
                chkCancelReview.Visible = true;
                if (chkApprove != null)
                {
                    chkApprove.Visible = true;

                }
                if (chkSendForApproval != null)
                {
                    chkSendForApproval.Visible = false;
                }
                SBMOfficer.Text = SBMOfficer.Text; //User.Identity.Name.ToString();

                    SBMComments.Enabled = true;
                    SBMOfficer.Enabled = true;

                }
                else if (User.IsInRole("ReviewRequester"))
             {
                if (chkApprove != null)
                {
                    chkApprove.Visible = false;
                }

                if (chkSendForApproval != null)
                {
                    chkSendForApproval.Visible = true;
                }
                 ManagerComments.Enabled = false;
                SBMComments.Enabled = false;
                SBMOfficer.Enabled = false;

                 reviewOfficer.Text = User.Identity.Name.ToString();

             }
                else
                {
                reviewOfficer.Text = User.Identity.Name.ToString();
                chkApprove.Visible = false;
                chkSendForApproval.Visible = false;
                DetailsView2.DefaultMode = DetailsViewMode.ReadOnly;
                }

                if (Status != null)
                {
                if (Status.Text != "O")
                {
                    DetailsView2.Enabled = false;

                }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                myMessageBox.myMessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString().Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", ""));
            }
            }



    protected void LinkButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String myurl;
        myurl = "Projections.aspx?accno=" + Convert.ToString(Session["Accno"]) + "&seqno=" + Convert.ToString(Session["ReviewSeqNo"]);

        Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>window.open('" + myurl + "','_blank');</script>");
        //Response.Redirect(myurl);

    }

    protected void LinkButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         String myurl;

        // myMessageBox.myMessageBox.Show(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ReportServer"].ToString());

        // myurl = "http://" + ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ReportServer"].ToString() + "/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fReview%2fReviewReport&rs:Command=Render&intaccno=" + Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["accountNo"]) + "&type=D&seqno=" + Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["seqno"]);
         //Added by Cherie 09/09/2009 to point users to review parallel report 
         myurl = "http://" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportServer"].ToString() + "/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fReview%2fReviewReportForParallel&rs:Command=Render&intaccno=" + Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["accountNo"]) + "&type=D&seqno=" + Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["seqno"]);

         Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>window.open('" + myurl + "','_blank');</script>");
         //Response.Redirect(myurl);
    }

    protected void DetailsView2_ItemUpdated(object sender, DetailsViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            CheckBox chkSendForApproval = (CheckBox)DetailsView2.FindControl("chkSend");
            CheckBox chkApprove = (CheckBox)DetailsView2.FindControl("chkApprove");

            if (chkSendForApproval.Checked && !chkApprove.Checked)
            {
                myMessageBox.myMessageBox.Show("The review is done from your side and has been sent to your manager for approval.");
            }
            else if (chkSendForApproval.Checked && chkApprove.Checked)
            {
                myMessageBox.myMessageBox.Show("This review is now complete!");
            }
            else
            {
                myMessageBox.myMessageBox.Show("Please ensure that the send for approval check box is checked if you want to send this review to your manager for approval");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            myMessageBox.myMessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString().Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", ""));
        }
    }
    protected void LinkButton5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("AnnualReview.aspx", false);
    }
    protected void chkCancelReview_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chkCancelReview = (CheckBox)DetailsView2.FindControl("chkCancelReview");
        TextBox txtStatus = (TextBox)DetailsView2.FindControl("txtStatus");

        if (chkCancelReview.Checked)
        {
            txtStatus.Text = "X";
        }
        else
        {
            txtStatus.Text = "O";
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: can you show what have you tried so far

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: Too less information to help. Provide some code, exceptions, errors etc. Along with that people would also need to know the input and expected output.

Comment: yes, sorry i"ve been trying to post my code. The indenting is such a hassle. still trying.

Comment: OK. I've edited my post and included code from .aspx and .cs pages respectively.

Comment: I only added the fields ÇRR to IOA...its should just accept user input in the textboxes

Comment: Indenting should be easy here. Paste in your code, select it, click the "code" button.

Answer (score 0):

if the 7 new fields no bound values，but the olds have, make sure the new files given values in your controller,you'd better show your code when you ask question.